# Trying to go from one view controller to another in a story board

Tags: iphone

I'm writting my first app using a storyboard.  Before I had the following code to go from one view controller to another.   But..this code needs a NibName. How would I do this going from screens created in a storyboard?

```
if (mDisplayCard==nil)
{
      mDisplayCard = [[cDisplayCard alloc]
                     initWithNibName:@"cDisplayCard"
                     bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
}
//  [ mDisplay SetUp];
[self.navigationController pushViewController: mDisplayCard animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

A line like the following will instantiate a new view controller from a storyboard:

```
    UIViewController *newViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"<identifier-from-storyboard>"];
```

It is assumed that your current view controller was instantiated from the same storyboard, so that `self.storyboard` is not `nil`. For the view controller that you want to instantiate, you'll have to make sure that you set a storyboard ID for it, which is what you'll put in for the identifier.